# Is it possible to get multiple MPMoviePlayerControllers in the same view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I have written code so that technically there should be two `MPMoviePlayerControllers` within the same view, both ready to play an audio file. What always happens is that one pops up and disappears, and the other comes up and stays, and is fully useable.

Any idea why one disappears? I'm not trying to play two at once, just want to give users the option to play from different sources.

Comment: Please post some code for how you are building your view.

Answer (score 2):

There can only be one active MPMoviePlayerController, it won't mind if the user didn't play it yet. I do not know the technical reason, but I do know that this is the normal behavior when you do that.

My advice would be to use AVAudioPlayer to achieve what you want. The sad part if that you will have to implement the UI of the player.